# post permalinks with dot in url don't resolve to correct page template

Tags: permalinks, page-template, apache

I have custom post type posts with the `.` character in the `post_name` field (thus the permalink) and it does not resolve to the correct page template. In this case instead of going to `single-cptslug.php` the permalink resolves to `index.php`. The `post_name` field gets it's data from a custom field and is updated via a custom query:

`$wpdb->query("UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts SET post_name = '" . $slug . "' WHERE ID = " . $post_id);`

Where `$slug` is something like `90.79.2.6`

I'm thinking the solution here may involve modifying the `.htaccess` file but I'm not sure and also have little to no `.htaccess` experience. Any help appreciated!

Comment: It might be easiest to set them up as custom page templates and then just select them from the dropdown list in the publish metabox.

Comment: I should have mentioned that even when doing that it still doesn't resolve to the right page template (still goes to `index.php`) if there's a dot `.` in the `post_name` field (thusly the permalink as well)

Comment: this sometimes happens when WordPress is confused about what type of request it is. what are your cpt rewrite settings? also, it could be a sanitization issue, maybe try [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/JosefJezek/ea16852d30bb4663e3b6), which will allow dots in slugs.

Comment: it's just rewriting the slug to the same slug. the problem with that plugin is that it alters the `sanitize_title` function for everything not just this isolated case. hence why I've avoided using this technique.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using the `index_template` filter to load the right template when the CPT single page is being incorrectly redirected to the index and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the slug of the CPT. Like so:

```
add_filter('index_template', 'wpse300393_resolve_cpts_with_dots_in_name');

function wpse300393_resolve_cpts_with_dots_in_name($templates = ''){
    if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'artwork') !== false ){
        $templates = locate_template( 'single-artwork.php' );
    }
    elseif( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'artist') !== false ){
        $templates = locate_template( 'single-artist.php' );
    }
    return $templates;
}
```